# Google Sheets reloading everything for each F5

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, browser

I'm facing a problem with Google Sheets reloading every cell for each time the sheet is opened (or F5).
This Spreadsheet have about 14500 lines and every F5 makes to start a new reloading for the very same spot:

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

After 40 ~ 60 minutes the Spreadsheet finish to reload:

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

If I press F5, will reload all again and will take about 40 ~ 60 minutes again.

I have another version of this sheets much less optimized with 15000 lines in another Google account (non workspace) and the problem doesn't happen there.
Any solution for this problem ?  Maybe something about cache ?

I already optimized the formulas of the Spreadsheet.
This problem don't happen with less line, like 5000 lines.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The question doesn't include enough details. While some times a screeshot might help, you should include enough details so others might reproduce the problem, i.e. it's. not clear if the mentioned number of rows are in a single sheet or are across multiple sheets, it's not clear if the spredsheets is using volatile funcionts, etc. P.S. Why do you need to press F5?

Comment: Hello @rubén,
I don't need to press F5 exactly. But if I need to close the spreadsheet and open it again after 10 minutes for example, I will have to wait for it to fully load again (40 to 60 minutes).

The F5 was just a practical example.

Comment: There is 6 sheets in this Spreadsheet.  And yes, there is formulas in each cell using at most INDEX and MATCH (vlookup alternative)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The practical example was no really practical, just saying that the spreadsheet takes that amount of time is better but it's not clear why it takes so long. Please [edit] the question to add all the relevant details. How many formulas have your spreadsheet? Are your formulas using open references? How many blank rows and columns have your spreadsheet?

Comment: Possible already answered in  https://stackoverflow.com/q/74315585/1595451

Comment: The question isn't about the speed to load.  The problem is the need to reload all everytime the Spreadsheet is opened like there isn't any cache, and the another Spreadsheet very similar (same goal, only less optimized formulas) doesn't happen this.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another google sheet and use importrange to pull the cells you want. You may need to stack multiple importrange formulas such as limiting each formula to a certain number of rows but it can all be done in a single cell per sheet.